Weyl's unitary trick over number fields?
One version of the unitary trick states that for a compact Lie group $G$ and representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ we can define $P = \int_G \rho(g)\rho(g)^*dg$ using the Haar measure, and find a principal square root $Q$ such that $Q^2 = P$. Then $\tau(g) = Q^{-1}\rho(g)Q$ is unitary.
Is there an analogue of this trick over $\mathbb{Q}$? Naively it appears that if I choose a number field $K$ containing sufficiently many square roots, say of the diagonal elements of $D$ where $P = M^{-1}DM$ and $Q=M^{-1}D^{1/2}M$, then $\tau(g)$ is indeed unitary for all $g \in G$. If I include square roots of $\frac{d_\rho}{|G|}$, then I can write down a unitary DFT over $K$.

I assume you mean "for finite groups." If you begin with a representation of a finite group $\rho : G \to GL_n(K)$ over any number field $K$ (and there's a nice argument that shows that every f.d. representation is defined over a number field), then pick an embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the restriction $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ of the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $K^n$ (which either does or does not have complex conjugation in it depending on whether the image of the embedding is real or complex). Then you can average this inner product over $G$ to obtain a $G$-invariant inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_G$ on $K^n$.
This is already a version of the unitary trick in the sense that it already embeds $G$ into some unitary group, namely the automorphisms of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_G$. However, if you want to embed $G$ into the unitary group, as in the automorphisms of the standard inner product on $K^n$, then you need to adjoin enough square roots that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_G$ becomes isomorphic to $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Concretely you can do this by adjoining every square root that appears when you perform the Gram-Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_G$, and in particular only finitely many square roots are required. So the result is a finite extension $L/K$, which is some other number field. (It is possible to "golf this down" a bit; maybe you only need to adjoin the square roots of the eigenvalues of the matrix of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_G$, or something.)

Thanks very much! Is $P$ the matrix corresponding to $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_G$? I did try Gram-Schmidt on the Gram matrix corresponding to the invariant inner product and kept getting an upper\lower triangular change-of-basis matrix $M$ that did not work, whereas $Q$ does.

@Jackson: I think so, although I'm not very familiar with the version of the unitary trick you're using. That's strange that Gram-Schmidt doesn't work, I don't know what's going on with that.

@Quiaochu For finite groups, $\langle x,y \rangle_G = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_G \langle \rho(g)x,\rho(g)y\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_G \langle x,\rho(g)^\rho(g)y \rangle = x^T\left(\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_G\rho(g)\rho(g)^\right) y = x^TPy$. For Gram-Schmidt, if $A$ is the Gram matrix for $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_G$, I was certainly getting $A=M.GS$ where $GS$ is orthonormal. $Q$ wasn’t upper/lower triangular, and contains square roots. Not sure what’s up with that either.
